# Importing external SCSS files with full paths - not working

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am trying to import the variables file into a sub-project. I want to have a single variables file, which would give theme to the both main and sub-project.

Hence, I am importing the variables file by using the full path in my sub-project, like :

```
@import "http://main-project-url/scss/_variables.scss"; 
OR 
@import url("http://main-project-url/scss/_variables.scss ");
```

However, I am getting errors while accessing those variables declared in _variables.scss file.
Can someone help me, please..!

Thanks in advance!
SuryaPavan

Comment: were you ever able to get this figured out?  I am trying to accomplish the same thing.  I have CodeKit and Intellij for compiling but it does not seem to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `@import` is overloaded in SASS, it's hard to tell but just because it compiles does not mean that the variables in .scss are getting interpreted.

You might look at **[remote-sass](https://github.com/joeellis/remote-sass)** which purports to do what you ask:

> RemoteSass is a small gem that allows Sass to import remote sass/scss
>   stylsheets over HTTP/S. With this, you can set up a central server to
>   serve your stylesheet assets and share css among your many
>   applications.